# Optimize SQL Server clustering key for insert/delete

Tags: sql-server, performance

I have some reporting activities that periodically deliver new data, my current strategy is to delete the old data and then insert the new, I use a range queries to move the reporting data in batches over a period of time.

My insert performance should be excellent, since all I'm doing here is appending to an ever increasing number, I'm using a `datetime2(7)` data type and `sysdatetime()` as default value.

However, I'm worried about fragmentation problems.

Old data will be the first to be written but eventually that data will get deleted and new data (that replaces this data) will get appended to the end.

My data should effectively roll into the future as it is updated.

I fully except all old data to eventually get deleted.

Do I still have to worry about fragmentation or would this do? I suspect this will have great performance but I'm still somewhat worried that SQL Server won't be able to reclaim the deleted space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understand that you will insert and delete in clustered index order. This design is very reasonable. You might still get fragmentation on inserts after a while because the inserts will reuse deleted pages. There might well be anomalies like single pages not being freed or other miscellaneous pages being present in the range used for inserting. In that sense, fragmentation causes more fragmentation as a stochastic process.

The only way to guarantee no fragmentation is to partition your data coarsely and put each partition in a new file group. This ensures that inserts are always at the end of the file (no where else to put them). Also, deletes will eventually cause an entire partition to become eligible for deletion.

Do you have nonclustered indexes? They might get fragmented, too.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Obviously there's a lot of things to consider but you've given me some interesting things to think about. Right now I'm researching clustering situations but I'll probably work my way towards index fragmentation at a later date.

Comment: When working with NCI's notice that there are basically two types: Nearly the same sort order as CI (e.g. DateTime) and random (UserName, EMail, ...). The first kind will behave the same way, the second kind will destroy performance.; Notice that inserting into a CI and NCI causes extreme fragmentation because SQL Server might allocate every second extend to each index! (Yes this is stupid). Filegroups to the rescue, again.

Comment: That's really good advice, thanks! When designing your database for performance/scalability there has to be tricks on how to deal with these issues, you don't happen to know of any particularly good resources? Or is it better to just go out a try each situation because you have to know your data to make those decisions?

Comment: Good advice regarding fragmentation is rare. I have never found a comprehensive resource on that (just the usual very generalized advice like "rebuild if fragmentation over 30%"). The file group idea comes from Project Madison (high scale DW appliance from Microsoft).